# Openlayers: How to tell if a layer is available on the map

Tags: vector, openlayers, layer, visible

I have a doubt. In openlayers, how should I know if a layer or map was added or not? For example, I have a layer control, to see if that layer is visible on the map.

In Leaflet I use it like this

```
my_layer_leaflet.on("add",function(){
);
```

And in openlayers?

```
var my_layer_openlayers = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'MyLayer',
    visible: false,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
            anchor: [0.5, 26],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'legend/image.png'
        }))
    }),
    source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return layer_geoserver;
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all,
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const isLayerExistsInMap = map.getLayers().getArray().includes(layer)
```

This worked for me, not quite sure if this is what you asked for or not.

Answer (score 0):

Place a single layer in a layerGroup an add a listener to the "change:layergroup" event:

```
var baseLayerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({layers: [layer_geoserver]});     
map.on("change:layergroup", function() {console.log("LayerGroup changed.")});
map.setLayerGroup(baseLayerGroup);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test. In fact, I need to test each layer if it's visible, if it is, I show the legend for each layer